# Parsing CSV in Python: Issues with Extracting Full Text from a Column

Tags: python, csv

I'm working on creating a function `get_data()` in Python that doesn't take any arguments. Its purpose is to load a file named `tx_deathrow_full.csv` and return a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary should have 18 fields corresponding to a row in the dataset.

An updated version of the dataset can be found in:

https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html

My Attempt:

I've written a piece of code that nearly accomplishes this:

```
def get_data():
    deathrow_data = []
    with open('tx_deathrow_full.csv', 'r') as fil:
        # Skips the first two rows (because of how the csv-file is given)
        next(fil)
        next(fil)

        reader = csv.reader(fil)
        for count, row in enumerate(reader):
            if count < 5:  # Sample of 5 rows
                row_data = row[0].split(',')
                row_dict = {
                    'Execution': int(row_data[0]),
                    'Date of Birth': row_data[1],
                    'Date of Offence': row_data[2],
                    'Highest Education Level': int(row_data[3]),
                    'Last Name': row_data[4],
                    'First Name': row_data[5],
                    'TDCJ Number': int(row_data[6]),
                    'Age at Execution': int(row_data[7]),
                    'Date Received': row_data[8],
                    'Execution Date': row_data[9],
                    'Race': row_data[10],
                    'County': row_data[11],
                    'Eye Color': row_data[12],
                    'Weight': int(row_data[13]),
                    'Height': row_data[14],
                    'Native County': row_data[15],
                    'Native State': row_data[16],
                    'Last Statement': row_data[17].rstrip(';') # To remove ';' in the end of the Last Statement.
                }
                deathrow_data.append(row_dict)
            else:
                break
    return deathrow_data
```

However, the issue arises with the 'Last Statement' field. It only captures text up to the first comma and cuts off the rest, or it fails to include all the text.

Example:

In the CSV file, row 6 reads:

```
550,1987-04-04,2008-04-06,11,Davila,Erick Daniel,999545,31,2009-02-27,2018-04-25,Black,Tarrant,Brown,161,"5' 11""",Tarrant,Texas,"Yes, I would like to say nephew it burns huh. You know I might have lost the fight but I'm still a soldier. I still love you all. To my supporters and family y'all hold it down. Ten Toes down right. That's all."
```

But my code returns:

```
550,1987-04-04,2008-04-06,11,Davila,Erick Daniel,999545,31,2009-02-27,2018-04-25,Black,Tarrant,Brown,161,"5' 11""",Tarrant,Texas,"Yes, I would like to say nephew it burns huh. You know I might have lost the fight but I'm still a soldier. I still love you all. To my supporters and family y'all hold it down. Ten Toes down right. That's all."
```

But when i run my code it only returns the following output:

```
[... , {'Execution': 550, 'Date of Birth': '1987-04-04', 'Date of Offence': '2008-04-06', 'Highest Education Level': 11, 'Last Name': 'Davila', 'First Name': 'Erick Daniel', 'TDCJ Number': 999545, 'Age at Execution': 31, 'Date Received': '2009-02-27', 'Execution Date': '2018-04-25', 'Race': 'Black', 'County': 'Tarrant', 'Eye Color': 'Brown', 'Weight': 161, 'Height': '"5\' 11"""', 'Native County': 'Tarrant', 'Native State': 'Texas', 'Last Statement': '"Yes'}, ...]
```

Note how 'Last Statement' is incorrectly truncated to '"Yes', instead of the full text.

[This is the CSV-file before downloading.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL12x.png)

[This is the CSV-file when i have downloaded in and opened it in Excel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg9ho.png)

**Note:**
Note that both snips has the example shown

**Question:**

How can I modify my code to ensure the full 'Last Statement' text is captured and included in the dictionary, considering the structure of the CSV file?

**What i have tried:**

I've attempted to use the Pandas library to address this issue, but without success as I am not familiar with its functionalities.

Additionally, I experimented with the following code snippet earlier, but later modified it to the version I previously shared, as it seemed closer to producing the desired result.

```
def get_data():
    """
    Returnerer deathrow_data opdateret!
    """
    deathrow_data = []  # Tom liste til rækkerne
    with open('tx_deathrow_full.csv', 'r') as fil:
            fieldnames1 = ['Execution', 'Date of Birth', 'Date of Offence',             'Highest Education Level', 'Last Name',
                      'First Name', 'TDCJ\nNumber', 'Age at Execution', 'Date Received', 'Execution Date', 'Race', 
                       'County', 'Eye Color', 'Weight', 'Height', 'Native County', 'Native State', 'Last Statement']
        reader = csv.DictReader(fil, fieldnames=fieldnames1, delimiter=';')   

        next(reader)  # Springer første linje over (header)
        next(reader)  # Springer anden linje over

        count = 0
        for row in reader:
            if count < 4:  # Laver en sample på 3 rækker
                deathrow_data.append(row)
                count += 1
            else:
                break
    return deathrow_data

result = get_data()
print(result)
```

Don't mind the danish comments in the code.

Comment: Why are you doing `row_data = row[0].split(',')`? `csv.reader()` already splits the line on commas.

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly be doing what you say. `row[0]` is just `550`, and `row[0].split(',')` will just have 1 element.

Comment: The result you're getting would happen if you used `split()` on the whole line instead of using `csv.reader()`.

Comment: The reason why i used `split()`is because else i'll get a ValueError that says: literal for int() with base 10: ',' (on ```'Highest Education Level': int(row_data[3]),```.

And when i remove int() then i'll be getting this output:

```[{'Execution': 5, 'Date of Birth': '5', 'Date of Offence': '3', ...]```

Comment: Something like what? You should just be using `row[n]` when assigning to the dictionary fields, not `row_data[n]`.

Comment: That's unfortunately not helping me.

Comment: I still don't understand why you're using `row_data` at all. It should be `row[3]`.

Comment: Please post **as text** a *small* sample of the actual .csv file and a [mcve] that can be copied and run *with no changes* to reproduce the problem with that data.  Pictures of data can't be copied and used for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `row[0].split(',')`. Just access the elements of the row returned by `csv.reader()` directly

```
def get_data():
    deathrow_data = []
    with open('tx_deathrow_full.csv', 'r') as fil:
        # Skips the first two rows (because of how the csv-file is given)
        next(fil)
        next(fil)

        reader = csv.reader(fil)
        for count, row_data in enumerate(reader):
            if count < 5:  # Sample of 5 rows
                row_dict = {
                    'Execution': int(row_data[0]),
                    'Date of Birth': row_data[1],
                    'Date of Offence': row_data[2],
                    'Highest Education Level': int(row_data[3]),
                    'Last Name': row_data[4],
                    'First Name': row_data[5],
                    'TDCJ Number': int(row_data[6]),
                    'Age at Execution': int(row_data[7]),
                    'Date Received': row_data[8],
                    'Execution Date': row_data[9],
                    'Race': row_data[10],
                    'County': row_data[11],
                    'Eye Color': row_data[12],
                    'Weight': int(row_data[13]),
                    'Height': row_data[14],
                    'Native County': row_data[15],
                    'Native State': row_data[16],
                    'Last Statement': row_data[17].rstrip(';') # To remove ';' in the end of the Last Statement.
                }
                deathrow_data.append(row_dict)
            else:
                break
    return deathrow_data
```

I tested this with the row 6 you posted in the question and it worked without error. The result is

```
[{'Execution': 550,
  'Date of Birth': '1987-04-04',
  'Date of Offence': '2008-04-06',
  'Highest Education Level': 11,
  'Last Name': 'Davila',
  'First Name': 'Erick Daniel',
  'TDCJ Number': 999545,
  'Age at Execution': 31,
  'Date Received': '2009-02-27',
  'Execution Date': '2018-04-25',
  'Race': 'Black',
  'County': 'Tarrant',
  'Eye Color': 'Brown',
  'Weight': 161,
  'Height': '5\' 11"',
  'Native County': 'Tarrant',
  'Native State': 'Texas',
  'Last Statement': 'Yes, I would like to say nephew it burns huh. You know I '
                    "might have lost the fight but I'm still a soldier. I "
                    "still love you all. To my supporters and family y'all "
                    "hold it down. Ten Toes down right. That's all."}]
```

Comment: There is something i completely miss then, when i run that code i get the following error code:

````File "/Users/sebastianposch/Desktop/PythonPoP/nytest/deathrow.py", line 14, in get_data
    'Execution': int(row_data[0]),
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '553,1983-09-24,2004-11-21,9,Young,Christopher Anthony,999508,34,2006-03-31,2018-07-17,Black,Bexar,Brown,216,"6\' 1""",Bexar,Texas,l want to make sure the Patel family knows I love them like they love````

Comment: That would happen if you have a line that's completely enclosed in quotes. Not like the line you posted in the question.

Comment: Alright, i deleted the file and re-downloaded it again, and now it works.

I'm both baffled and grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, but in addition to Barmars answer, I'd suggest to:

1. open the file with with newline='', because [the docs suggest to do so](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), and
2. explicitly pass the delimiter: reader = csv.reader(fil, delimiter=',')

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the csv module's DictReader?  It'll read the header then read each row into a dict with the fieldnames from the header as key names.  Given a simple CSV like:

```
input.csv
---------
Col1,Col2,Col3
r1c1,r1c2,r1c3
r2c1,r2c2,r2c3
r3c1,r3c2,r3c3
```

```py
with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    print(list(reader))
```

prints:

```py
[
    {"Col1": "r1c1", "Col2": "r1c2", "Col3": "r1c3"},
    {"Col1": "r2c1", "Col2": "r2c2", "Col3": "r2c3"},
    {"Col1": "r3c1", "Col2": "r3c2", "Col3": "r3c3"},
]
```

I found the older dataset from pydango/selectstarsql/sql_buddy, which stops at 2018.  Does your header look like this, with the line break (I assume so because you skip the first two lines and comment about how the CSV was made)?

```
Execution,Date of Birth,Date of Offence,Highest Education Level,Last Name,First Name,"TDCJ
Number",Age at Execution,Date Received,Execution Date,Race,County,Eye Color,Weight,Height,Native County,Native State,Last Statement
```

I recommend either editing the CSV by hand and just removing the line break after TDCJ, or preprocess the file in Python, with something like:

```py
with open("input_tx_dr.csv", newline="") as f:
    text = f.read()

# Try replacing with newline or CRLF
text = text.replace("TDCJ\nNumber", "TDCJ Number")
text = text.replace("TDCJ\r\nNumber", "TDCJ Number")

with open("input_tx_dr_fixed.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Now, with a good header you can make DictReader do most of the work:

```py
from datetime import datetime

samples = []

with open("input_tx_dr_fixed.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 5:
            break

        for k in [
            "Execution",
            "Highest Education Level",
            "TDCJ Number",
            "Age at Execution",
            "Weight",
        ]:
            row[k] = int(row[k])

        for k in [
            "Date of Birth",
            "Date of Offence",
            "Date Received",
            "Execution Date",
        ]:
            row[k] = datetime.strptime(row[k], r"%Y-%m-%d")

        samples.append(row)
```